# error C2601: 'main' : local function definitions are illegall - MS VS 2013 Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a small program in C++. When I try to compile it using MS VS 2013 Compiler I get an error: "C2601: 'main' : local function definitions are illegall". What does it mean? My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
int n;
int pomocniczaLiczba;
using namespace std;
int ciong(int n){
    switch (n)
    {
    case 1:
        return 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
    default:
        pomocniczaLiczba = ciong(n - 2) + ciong(n - 1) * ciong(n - 1);
        return pomocniczaLiczba;
        break;
    }
int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    cout >> ciong(n);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: And the typical rudeness of stack overflow shines through... You could have phrased that attack much more politely and still made the point.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Very nice to hear your opinion. As you see, this was asked more than 1 year ago. Now, I'm a quite experienced programmer and I know how to debug programs. And now, when looking at the code I can easly say that there's a missing brace.

Comment: Yes.  This could have easily been spotted but you didn't. No worries.  The person making the comment should have been more polite to you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your bracketing is broken. The net result is that you are attempting to define your `main` function inside `ciong`. And C++ does not support nested function definitions. Hence the compiler error.

The code should be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int ciong(int n)
{
switch (n)
{
case 1:
    return 1;
    break;
case 2:
    return 2;
    break;
default:
    int pomocniczaLiczba = ciong(n - 2) + ciong(n - 1) * ciong(n - 1);
    return pomocniczaLiczba;
    break;
}
} // <----- Oops, this was missing in your code

int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;
cout << ciong(n) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

And there are other bugs. For example, you meant `cout << ciong(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2013 C++, I got compilation errors that I couldn't explain.

The compilation errors were:

*main.cpp(325): error C2601: 'FLAG' : local function definitions are illegal

main.cpp(323): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched

main.cpp(326): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'main.cpp(323)' was matched*

But there was nothing wrong with my code. I counted all brackets and the number matched. There weren't any function inside another function.

I solved it by removing all "//" comments from the source code. It seems that the reason for that is bad line formatting which causes the compiler to miss a line break, so the line after a comment is treated as a comment as well.

For example:

```
// This is a comment

This_is_a_line;
```

is treated as:

```
// This is a comment This_is_a_line;
```

There are many posts of the net about similar problems and some even suggested that they could be caused by a memory (RAM) fault on the machine, so before you replace your RAM, just remove the comments and see...

- Michael Haephrati מיכאל האפרתי

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much for posting this. I just faced the same problem with MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, and was about to explode. For me, ADDING one empty // around where error is pointing solved the issue, although I can't even guess what is happening.