# command line parsing using a vector

Tags: c++

I get this error using this code from stroustrup book
    c++ programming language page 254

> Error 1   error C2601: 'arguments' : local function
>       definitions are illegal

## Can I get a working code example putting the arguments into a vector?

```
vector<string> arguments(int argc, char* argv[]) // this line
{
vector<string> cmd_args;
for (int i = 0; i!=argc; ++i)
cmd_args.push_back(argv[i]);
return cmd_args;
}
```

Comment: You put dot after char instead  of *.

Comment: You really need to pay attention to indentation since that helps avoid serious bugs and confusion. I'd also strongly recommend you use braces `{ ... }` for *all* blocks while you're learning, no exceptions, even for simple things like a `return`. Even highly experienced programmers make mistakes with single-line `for` and `if` statements.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem might be your compiler.  I was to compile and run your code in both VS2105 and Code::Blocks/Cygwin GCC, without any problems.

Comment: is there any chance you forgot to end (closing `}`) previous function body?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2601: 'main' : local function definitions are illegall - MS VS 2013 Compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460076/error-c2601-main-local-function-definitions-are-illegall-ms-vs-2013-compi)